# Using GetJsonAsync for List of Tuples

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor

I am working on a Blazor App. I have an API method that returns a `List<Tuple<string,int>>`.

**API response in Postman:**

```
[
    {
        "Item1": "1",
        "Item2": 1
    },
    {
        "Item1": "24",
        "Item2": 2
    }
]
```

**API call in razor page:**

```
private object dataSource;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
    dataSource = await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<Tuple<string,int>>>("/Api/Default/GetProjectsList");
}
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported.
```

I understand the error.

Is there a generic type that can be parsed by `GetJsonAsync` which can be also be returned from the API method?

Or Is there a way to parse this tuple? Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

This is a limitation when using the new `System.Text.Json`. See [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#deserialization-behavior) ：

> *Deserialization to reference types without a parameterless constructor isn't supported.*

Since `Tuple<string,int>` has no parameterless constructor, it fails.

As a walkaround, you can deserialize the tuple with the classic [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) for the present:

```cs
var resp = await Http.GetStringAsync("/Api/Default/GetProjectsList");
var list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tuple<string,int>>>(resp);



foreach(var i in list){
    Console.WriteLine("--------");
    Console.WriteLine(i.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(i.Item2);
    Console.WriteLine("--------");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is (currently) not possible to deserialization to types without a parameterless constructor when using the build-in System.Text serializer.

However, you can always create a small wrapper object:

```
public class MyItem
{ 
   public MyItem {}
   public string Item1 {get; set;}
   public int Item2 {get; set;}
}

and then 

 await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<MyItem>>(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [Workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1519#issuecomment-572751931) and use a ValueTuple

To be short, `System.Text.Json` currently does not support deserialize ValueTypeTuple. This is due to deserialize ValueTypeTuple requires deserializing field.(Currently deserialize doest support field, see [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/876)

The workaround create a custom Json convertor as well as coresponding Json Convertor Factory, than register this Json Convertor in asp.net core global json option. In this case you don't need to create wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

## Use a Value Tuple

With a C# [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-7.0) you can also name the children.

```
await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<Tuple<string,int>>>("/Api/Default/GetProjectsList");
```

becomes:

```
await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<(string foo, int bar)>>("/Api/Default/GetProjectsList");
```